# Expression.Bind with Condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I have an entity which contains a collection of other entity (among others)

```
public class A{
 public ICollection<B> Bs {get;set;}
}
```

I want to implement dynamic lambda expression which will select some properties and "Bs" collection as well. What I am doing now is:

```
FieldInfo bS= typeof(A).GetField("Bs");
MemberBinding bind = Expression.Bind(bS, SomeExpression);
```

My problem is that I want to select only bS which are matching my condition for example

```
Expression.Bind(bS, x => x.Value > 0);
```

Is there some way I can adjust "SomeExpression" variable to apply condition?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `Expression.Bind` is for assigning a value to a property when creating a new object. I don't think that is what you need?

Comment: Can you please let me know if the answer solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment response I edited this answer.

You can look at

https://github.com/PoweredSoft/DynamicLinq/blob/054055487710bc790c05b922d098b4495d52f5d2/PoweredSoft.DynamicLinq/Helpers/QueryableHelpers.cs#L119

```
public static IQueryable Select(IQueryable query, List<(SelectTypes selectType, string propertyName, string path)> parts, Type destinationType = null)
{
```

Hope fully I can help you getting started it shows how to do member init and binding property to a type that you are selecting with.

Comment: I know how to implement dynamic WHERE. I am strugling with dynamic select within which I can have another select with WHERE clause so unfortunately this does not help.